# Skipping the first line of the .csv in Map reduce java

Tags: java, mapreduce, bigdata

As mapper function runs for every line , can i know the way how to skip the first line. For some file it consists of column header which i want to ignore

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In mapper while reading the file, the data is read in as key-value pair. The key is the byte offset where the next line starts. For line 1 it is always zero. So in mapper function do the following

```
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException {
        try {
            if (key.get() == 0 && value.toString().contains("header") /*Some condition satisfying it is header*/)
                return;
            else {
                // For rest of data it goes here
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks i had used the same thing after lots of try !!

Comment: I think `keys == 0` should be `keys.get() == 0`. Since LongWritable can't be compared with int directly. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yup. Need to use `get()`. Thanks! @yusong

Comment: if the key is Other than LongWritable then>

Comment: @mandrek It is always line number for files in `map`, hence `Longwritable` type key.

Answer (score 2):

As the file can be stored in multiple nodes, we cant say in which machine the header part present and which mapper is processing that part of file.
We can filter out the header in the Mapper itself.For this you have to know the headers. For example

```
 String[] cols= line.tokenize();
 if(cols[0].equals("header")) {
    // skip
 } else {
   // emit
}
```