# Hadoop Min Max Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new in Hadoop. I try to write a program to get the min and max values per year.The data set looks like:

```
Product code,Station number,Year,Month,Monthly Precipitation Total (millimetres),Quality
IDCJAC0001,023093,1978,01,4.6,Y
IDCJAC0001,023093,1978,02,11.4,Y
IDCJAC0001,023093,1978,03,4.8,Y
IDCJAC0001,023093,1978,04,46.2,Y
IDCJAC0001,023093,1978,05,52.7,Y
```

I am using mac and conduct Hadoop on my school cluster. 
Here is my command line:

```
hadoop jar hw1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /samplefolder/IDCJAC0001Data1.csv /OUTPUT
```

But the result shows error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /samplefolder/IDCJAC0001Data1/csv

I've searched on the website and try different commands such as `hadoop jar hw1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.mycompany.hw1.SolarMinMax /samplefolder/IDCJAC0001Data1.csv /OUTPUT`, but the result is same...

Please help me with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run with

```
hadoop jar hw1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.mycompany.hw1.SolarMinMax /samplefolder/IDCJAC0001Data1.csv /OUTPUT
```

and then change your code to be

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
```

because `args[0]` is the class name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the code, and run with the command line as you said, but the result still shows: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mycompany.hw1.SolarMinMax

Comment: OK then your JAR mustn't be built correctly, or the class isn't in the package you said.

Comment: Oh, it works. But it shows another error...java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Monthly Precipitation Total (millimetres)"

Comment: As for this new problem, it looks like you're reading the header row, and you're also not checking your data to make sure that each entry is actually a number. When writing MR apps you always have to assume your data won't be clean. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541109/skipping-the-first-line-of-the-csv-in-map-reduce-java